# No such file or directory issue when using github codes on Colab

Tags: github, directory, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working on Geogramint tool, and here is my problem:

When a github repo is cloned to the colab, it usually requires updating the path with the name of the main directory.

Code on github:

```
git clone https://github.com/Alb-310/Geogramint.git  
cd Geogramint/  
pip install -r requirements.txt  

python geogramint.py # for GUI mode  
python geogramint.py --help # for CLI mode
```

Code to run it on colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/Alb-310/Geogramint.git  
!cd Geogramint/  
!pip install -r **Geogramint**/requirements.txt  
!python3 **Geogramint**/geogramint.py --help # for CLI mode
```

So on colab, giving the right directory usually fixes the issue for the tools I use. However, with this specific app, I received the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'appfiles/config.ini'

So clearly, the app cannot find the directory since it is located in 'Geogramint/appfiles/config.ini'

For more clarification:

```py
/content/Geogramint/CLI/settings_cli.py:44 in saveConfig                                         │
│                                                                                                  │
│   41 │   │   │   │   │    'HASH': str(api_hash),                                                 │
│   42 │   │   │   │   │    'PHONE': str(phone_number)}                                            │
│   43 │   config['REPORT'] = {'EXTENDED': extended_report}                                        │
│ ❱ 44 │   **with open('appfiles/config.ini', 'w') as configfile:**                                    │
│   45 │   │   config.write(configfile)                                                            │
│   46 │   return loadConfig()
```

How can I order it to go the right directory?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: UPDATE: I downloaded settings_cli.py and changed directory there to 'Geogramint/appfiles/config.ini' and uploaded new file to colab  and it worked.